# Handle client's ethereum transaction through node backend

Tags: node.js, npm, web3js

I want to log a user's ethereum transaction along with other meta into a database only if the transaction was successful. An example would be they successfully staked an nft on the clientside and signed it with their metamask

```
if (txSuccessful) fetch('/someApiToLogDataOfTx', {
```

But I want to do it without having to expose the api, so that means the entire tx would have to be processed through a backend that would essentially do the same?

With this idea, any tx would have to be signed before sending it to the api?

frontend

```
    var raw = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw, function (err, transactionHash) {
      fetch('/someApiToLogDataOfTx', { raw } 
    });
```

backend

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log) // some logging to db
```

Is this right? or is there some overthinking here?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible at least with Metamask, the most popular wallet provider.
It does not let you just sign a transaction without broadcasting it.
You can read about it more in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475).
Although many people were requesting this functionality, it has been rejected foremost because of the `nonce` handling issues that would arise.